# Selenium запуск тестов в одном браузере

Tags: ubuntu, python-3.x, selenium

В папке находятся 50 простых тестов написанных на python3.
При запуске их по очереди

```
for i in `ls /path/*.py`; do python3 $i; done
```

Каждый раз открывается браузер.
Можно ли как то сделать чтобы все эти скрипты выполнялись в одном браузере?

Пример простого скрипта:

```
from selenium.webdriver.firefox.webdriver import WebDriver

success = True
vd = WebDriver()
#АДРЕС САЙТА ДЛЯ ПОСТИНГА
urlnow = "http://www.google.ru"
#ОТКРЫВАЕМ URL
vd.get(urlnow)

vd.quit()
```

Answer (score 1):

Всё просто)))))

Вы делаете управляющий скрипт, в котором есть цикл `for` и больше ничего нет. И вы берёте исполняемые скрипты в каждом из которых (помимо всего прочего) есть импорт библиотеки, команда запуска браузера и команда закрытия браузера

```
from selenium.webdriver.firefox.webdriver import WebDriver

vd = WebDriver()
vd.quit()
```

Это значит, что у вас *импорт библиотеки браузера*, *включение браузера* и *выключение браузера* находятся **внутри цикла**. То есть у вас вот такая конструкция:

```
ЦИКЛ:
    запуск.браузера
    тело цикла
    выключение.браузера
```

Именно поэтому и происходит запуск и выключение браузера каждую итерацию цикла.

Что-бы такого не было, вам нужно вынести импорт библиотеки, запуск и выключение за цикл, то есть написать их в управляющем скрипте в виде конструкции:

```
запуск.браузера
ЦИКЛ:
    тело цикла
выключение.браузера
```

Это значит, что вам нужно отредактировать все 50 исполняемых скриптов, и удалить в них команды запуска и выключения браузера, а импорт библиотеки и эти команды нужно написать в управляющем скрипте.